# How to use <icon> in web.xml for Java web application?

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, servlets, servlet-3.0

I'm  create one maven web application. In web.xml there is one tag named is `<icon>`.

what is use case and how to use `<icon>` tag in my web application ?
please help me.

**Web.xml :-**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">

<icon>
    <small-icon>image/iconSmall.gif</small-icon>
</icon>

<!-- ************ Servlet Declaration *************** -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>MyFirstServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.example.servlet.MyFirstServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>MyFirstServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/MyFirstServlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

icon element speicifes small and large image used to represent web application in GUI tool.  size is 16x16 px and  size is 32x32 pixel . File type should be .gif or .jpg

Ref : http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11035_01/wls100/webapp/web_xml.html#wp1070143

Comment: Raja :- thanks for ans.. but  i did't get meaning of this statement "The icon element specifies the location within the Web application for a small and large image used to represent the Web application in a GUI tool.".  please give me brief detail into this.

Comment: I never made it practcially done. But below is something I collected from Google Search :P
"These tags provide information for the deployment tools or the application server resource management tools. 
The images are used tools if they want to represent the Web Application visually. " 

Hence I assume it is not for favicon ( Browser window icon ) but may be used in some application servers for graphical representation of application. Hope it helps ? or may be someone who actually worked on application servers can help on it.

Comment: Ref : Professional Apache Tomcat 6 - Page Number 144

Comment: Raja :- Please give me link  of  " Professional Apache Tomcat 6 ".

Comment: The author of the book is Vivek Chopra and Wrox publications. Page Number 144 has the info I quoted above